# If statement not working as expected when importing csv data

Tags: python, csv, if-statement

Sorry, if the problem is very basic, I am very new to python.

In the code, I am trying to add up values in column 5 of the CSV file - if the value in the first column is a certain value.

If the value of column 1 is equal to 1, I want to add the value of column 5 of the same value to a cumulative sum.

When debugging everything above the `if` statement is working as expected, but then `if` statement isn't updating the value for the variable.

```
with open('dataset1.csv') as csv_file:
      csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
      print('File has been imported')

      csv_headings = next(csv_reader)
    
      Cumlative_Cases=0
    
      for line in csv_reader:
        get_id=line[0]
        new_case=line[4]

        print(get_id)
        #print(new_case)
        
        if get_id == 1:
            Cumlative_Cases = Cumlative_Cases + new_case

        print(Cumlative_Cases)
```

Comment: Convert it to `int` - you are comparing a string with `1`

Comment: as @alaniwi suggested, it is likely the value of [0] is not an int. Mocking the CSV file load, I can confirm your code is working as intended with all the values as integers.

Comment: @JamesPowis I'd put it as more than merely "likely" - `line` will contain a list of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
      csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
      print('File has been imported')
      csv_headings = next(csv_reader)
    
      Cumlative_Cases=0
    
      for line in csv_reader:
        get_id = int(line[0])
        new_case = int(line[4])
        print(get_id)
        #print(new_case)
        
        if get_id == 1:
            Cumlative_Cases = Cumlative_Cases + new_case
        print(Cumlative_Cases)
```